# Quickblox CONTENT versus CUSTOM OBJECTS files

Tags: quickblox

With QB release 1.8 it is now possible to upload files to classes in Custom Objects module.

- Is there any performance differences between Custom Objects and Content? Can I just use
  Custom Objects to upload all files in my app?

In Custom Objects module I can have meta information associated with each uploaded file like visibility (public/private), status (approved, rejected), etc, which I can't in Content module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are features of each storage:

**Content**

- no file size limit, up to 5TB
- allows to use file public url

**Custom Objects**

- max 32Mb file size
- no public urls to files
- great CustomObjects API like filters, permissions etc